# Is there an industry standard definition for "load"?

Tags: power, energy, load

I come across load meaning either power or energy from time to time in the context of residential loads or load forecasting. As such I was wondering if there is a convention as to whether "load" more often refers to power (kW) or energy (kWh)?

I've recently adopted the language of "demand" for power and "consumption" for energy, as I think they offer a little bit more clarity.

Comment: `load` is the usage of supplied `energy`

Answer (score 0):

Power is an instantaneous value, a singular moment in time. Energy is power across a time unit. There is a lot of misuse of the term "power" because, for example, we refer to the Utility as the "Power Company", ergo the stuff they give us is power. But what we actually use and PAY FOR is energy.

Load is simply the work being performed by that energy, a component of the energy consumption, because energy consumption can be defined as load *+ losses*.

Comment: They give us power, we give them whatever the time derivative of money is.

Comment: I prefer to think of it as renting electrons, but they're really stuffy and you have to return your last electron to get a new one.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of english words with meanings that depend on context. Load probably refers to power most often, but it can also refer to the equipment that converts electric power to mechanical work, light or heat that serves some useful purpose. Demand usually refers to power, but it can refer to the peak power or the maximum power that occurs over a short time during a 24 hour period.

Consumption is a ok term for energy, but electric energy is not so much consumed as converted.

I would argue that it is best to understand and use the terms power and energy rather than demand and consumption. However, those terms are useful in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

> I come across load meaning either power or energy from time to time in the context of residential loads or load forecasting.  As such I was wondering if there is a convention as to whether "load" more often refers to power (kW) or energy (kWh)?

Specifically both, which in this case means either.  The "Load" is the device or set of devices being referred to which convert electrical energy.  When talking about power consumption/energy use, "load" is used to refer to both power and energy, as well as current and many other things depending on context.  Context will determine which is relevant, and it is the device(s) that has/have these properties that the word actually refers to.  So, as far as convention, it is convention to refer to that which converts electrical power as a load rather than other words like burden or weight which mean the same thing.  Using it as a verb or as a more specific noun to refer to one of it's properties simply evolved from this convention for convenience, and is still adequately specific so from the engineering perspective I don't believe it is improper or incorrect although it may cause the odd grammatical flaw.

Perspective matters too.  It is acceptable to refer to a city, a factory, a building, a desktop computer, an LED fan in the computer, or the LEDs or fan motor as a load, with context being used to indicate the difference.

I'll just add that "Load" is also used in place of "thermal load", "Aerodynamic load", in the same way and again context indicates the difference.

> I've recently adopted the language of "demand" for power and "consumption" for energy, as I think they offer a little bit more clarity.

Demand is a property of a load as well, in this case, power(W/kW) averaged over a period of time.  I think these words are adequately defined once you sort out context, and many end up being specific to an industry because of the perspective they operate from.

I know about Demand not from school but from working with building operators.  The buildings contract allows an average of X power average over an hour, a larger amount average over 15 minutes and a larger amount average over 5 minutes.  These figures are Demand.  If they start too many large loads at once and mess up their power factor or draw more current than they are allowed to during that time period, they are said to have "blown demand" and it was basically the one mistake those guys really didn't want to make as it would massively increase the building's power bill for an entire month.